# avoid space in parameter query

Tags: sql-server

I have this:

```
DECLARE @Client NVARCHAR(25),
        @sqlStr NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sqlStr = 'INSERT INTO #GetDisplayName (displayName) SELECT displayName FROM OPENROWSET
            (''ADSDSOObject'', ''adsdatasource''; ''mxi\santos'';''Consultant1'', 
             ''SELECT displayName FROM ''''LDAP://mxiadsrv/DC=mxi,DC=com'''' 
             where sAMAccountName=''''' + @Client + ''''''')'

SET @sqlStr = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@sqlStr,' ',' %'),'% ',''),'%','')
```

And in one of my loops I get:

```
INSERT INTO #GetDisplayName (displayName) SELECT displayName FROM OPENROWSET     ('ADSDSOObject', 'adsdatasource'; 'mxi\santos';'Consultant1',       
'SELECT displayName FROM ''LDAP://mxiadsrv1/DC=mxi,DC=com''       
where sAMAccountName=''fallot ''')
```

The problem is the extra space in the sAMAccountName=''**fallot** ''') section

How can I avoid this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
where sAMAccountName=''''' + rtrim(@Client) + ''''''')'
```